# Parsing HTML without any structure constraints

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

I have an application where I receive an HTML string inside a `<template>` element, with some custom templating elements mixed in. I then want to parse the contents as DOM elements. (This was previously done server-side.)

Previously, I tried to use `DOMParser` to parse the templates, but this failed when e.g. `<tr>` was found at the root of the template (because rows require a table around them). With `<template>`, everything worked.

```js
console.log(thisworks.outerHTML);
```

```html
<template id="thisworks">
<tr><td><x:custom>Sample Text</x:custom></td></tr>
</template>
```

However, when the content inside the `<template>` is not structurally valid HTML (e.g. only `<option>`/`<optgroup>` allowed inside `<select>`), the browser attempts to "fix" the structure, breaking the custom templating parts, along with some more things.

```js
console.log(thisdoesnt.outerHTML);
```

```html
<template id="thisdoesnt">
<table><x:custom><tr><td>Sample Text</td></tr></x:custom></table>
<select><x:custom><option>Sample Text</option></x:custom></select>
</template>
```

I also don't want to just use an XML parser, because the source might not be valid XML, and converting it is a lot of work with my amount of existing code.

Is there a way (preferably without megabytes of dependencies) to cleanly parse DOM in JavaScript, with HTML syntax, but without HTML's constraints?

Comment: *“Is there a way (preferably without megabytes of dependencies) to cleanly parse DOM in JavaScript, with HTML syntax, but without HTML's constraints?”* — No, there isn’t, because that would require not using an HTML parser. *“the browser attempts to "fix" the structure, breaking the custom templating parts, along with some more things”* — that’s just how all HTML parsers in browsers work, because the parsing algorithm in the HTML requires them to. If you want to avoid that behavior I guess your only alternative is to not use an HTML parser but instead write your own custom parser

Comment: @sideshowbarker Well then, guess I'll just have to use reg̞ͣe͔x͖ t͇͇̰ͪ̌̍o͓͈ ̱̗p̣ͧȧ̤ͅrͬ͋̇͌͌̓҉̮͍̰̰s͔̞͕͖͕̺ͨ͡ḙ̜̺͙̆͠ ̲̽i͇̞̬͓̬̰̮͛ͥͭͭ̌͋t͌̈́͊̿ͧ̃